# Como cambiar las URL de sitio web para que sean amigables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, seo

En este momento tengo que implementar unas mejoras de SEO en el portal que desarrollé, entre ellas me piden que tengo que cambiar las URs para que sean mas amigables.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo que no implique cambiar todos los nombres a los controladores y métodos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias adaptar las url de los action usando el atributo `[Route]`

[Understanding URL Rewriting and URL Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC (MVC5) with Examples](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples)

```
[RoutePrefix("students")]
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    [Route("college-students")]
    public ActionResult ShowStudents() { ... }
    //resto codigo
    ...
}
```

Como veras el nombre del metodo del action es diferente a la url con la cual accedes pudiendo redefinirlo con el atributo